# Trying to add variables

Tags: javascript, variables, calculator

I'm trying to build a calculator in Google Script using Sheets.
Here, I'm using two inputs, (yes, they are already given var, they are stored) and trying to add them in order to get an output that will be further be automatically put into cell B2.

```
function doMath() {
    var add = (value1 + value2);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').setValue(add);
}
```

But this error message keeps popping up:

> ReferenceError: "value1" is not defined.

I'm fairly new to programming, so I have no idea what the problem is.

EDIT: Here is where I define inputs:

```
  function readInput() {
var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
var value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').getValue();
```

EDIT2: Keep in mind that these are two seperate functions. Is that the problem?
And also note that the value of cells A1 and B1 are 8 and 9 respectively. (as an example)

Comment: That is because `value1` and `value2` are not defined **anywhere** in your code.

Comment: The problem is that `value1` is not defined. Where are you setting it?

Comment: Where in your code do you declare `value1` and `value2`, and where is this function called from?

Comment: Can you post here longer piece of your code (even with declaration)... maybe you declare them in different namespace, maybe something else... we are not able to indentify it from just this short code.

Comment: Is `value1` the id of the input element?

Answer (score 0):

Your value1 and value2 are not defined. They are defined in a different function. Try this.

```
function doMath() {
    var value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
    var value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').getValue();
    var add = (value1 + value2);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').setValue(add);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about scope in js. When you define a var inside a function, it will local to this function (ie won't be defined outside). The solution is to define them outside (ie make them global).

```
var value1, value2;

function doMath() {
    var add = (value1 + value2);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B2').setValue(add);
}


function readInput() {
    value1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();
    value2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').getValue();
}
```

To avoid polluting the global namespace. You can enclose this in a self invoking anonymous function:

```
(function(){
 // your code…
})();
```